# I have been trying to fetch an API and I keep getting : SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON

Tags: javascript, api

I have tried several times to get an API using fetch and the promise I got is giving me headache. this is the error I am getting, Unexpected end of JSON input

I have looked up online including stack overflow but the solutions they gave out in the previous questions were not solving mine. this looks pretty unusual to me

```
search(){
        let{ingredients, dish} = this.state;
        const url = `http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=${ingredients}&q=${dish}`;
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log('recipe', json))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: The error suggests that that API is not returning valid JSON.

Comment: But how can I fix that?

Comment: The first thing I would do is see what the API *does* return. Maybe there's an error? What's the status code? Check your network tab. Another possibility is that the API has a bug, in which case it needs to be fixed by whoever built the API.

Comment: It looks like the recipe site doesn't have CORS configured to allow cross origin requests. It also doesn't support HTTPS, which would be another issue if the site running the request does.

Comment: The API returns good json, I just checked: `{"title":"Recipe Puppy","version":0.1,"href":"http:\/\/www.recipepuppy.com\/","results":[{"title":"Simple Tuna Pasta Salad","href":"http:\/\/www.recipezaar.com\/Simple-Tuna-Pasta-Salad-64320","ingredients":"albacore tuna, celery, peas, mayonnaise, pasta (in general), salt","thumbnail":"http:\/\/img.recipepuppy.com\/38156.jpg"},` etc.

Comment: Can you please share the code you used to get back the JSON?

Comment: this is what I am still getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: I think there is more to that error, after several trial on other browsers, I checked the network and I saw status code of "200". but the console log is not returning any object. What could be blocking the API request?

Comment: I didn't use Javascript, you can even paste that API URL into a browser and it returns the JSON

Comment: When I pasted that url in a browser I got the json but my code is showing error with my Javascript syntax. I need help here please

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't get the JSON with a Javascript fetch either, because I'm using https and **recipepuppy.com** is using http. It gives me an error, although different from what you wrote. I do get the JSON using a simple GET request in Perl.

Comment: None of these answers solved the problem expect the person who used another language to solve it who can close but since I do my backend with NodeJS and not PHP, none of the answers help. Please can I get answer from someone who using either Reactjs or NodeJS

Comment: Is the `fetch` running on the NodeJS backend or in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You json in response (which you provide in question comment) is invalid

```js
let json='{"title":"Recipe Puppy","version":0.1,"href":"http:\/\/www.recipepuppy.com\/","results":[{"title":"Simple Tuna Pasta Salad","href":"http:\/\/www.recipezaar.com\/Simple-Tuna-Pasta-Salad-64320","ingredients":"albacore tuna, celery, peas, mayonnaise, pasta (in general), salt","thumbnail":"http:\/\/img.recipepuppy.com\/38156.jpg"}'

JSON.parse(json); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Your server needs to join additional `]}` at the end of returned json

### UDATE

You need to turn on cors in your server - if you don't have access to server you need to use some cors-proxy e.g. below (but not use it for production)

```js
async function load(ingredients,dish) {
    let url=`http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=${ingredients}&q=${dish}`;
    let nocors= `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`
    let data = await (await fetch(nocors+url)).json();
    console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="load('fish','taco')">Load</button>
```

Comment: I left that snippet of JSON code in a comment as an example only, it was truncated, with "etc." on the end, not meant to provide the whole payload. As I recall, the server had it right.

Comment: Update question and add full response json

Comment: I did JSON.parse(json) too

Comment: This is not the problem. The server returns valid JSON when you access the URL directly in a browser. However, when trying to use `fetch` you get a CORS error. In Firefox this is the message shown in the console: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=fish&q=taco. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it's a CORS issue. Running the fetch in Firefox gives me this error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=fish&q=taco. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). [[Learn more]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default)

Chrome gives this message:

> Access to fetch at 'http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=fish&q=taco' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

If I add the `mode: 'no-cors'` option to the `fetch` statement, I get error messages similar to what you describe.

Firefox:

> SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Chrome:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do, because the server has to send that header to allow cross-origin requests.